# How to start a jupyter notebook terminal from within the jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Where visiting the notebook server in the up-right corner. I am able to create a terminal by clicking new and terminal.

[image: new button]

how can I do this from within a Jupyter notebook running on that server? meaning some command to run in a cell.

Comment: Is the terminal option in the menu disabled (greyed out)? Terminals are unavailable if it can't import the terminado package. In master, there's also a config option to explicitly disable them.

Comment: no its available. i want to spawn these terminals and in a different question later on i want to send commands to them.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your question. You can create a new terminal programmatically with a POST request to `/api/terminals`, or by sending a browser window to `/terminals/{name}` with any unused name. Sending commands to it programmatically might be trickier, and might depend on what it is you want to do.